# Ruby time multiplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, activesupport

Can some break this down for me? In my mind 5 minutes squared is 25 minutes

```
irb(main):014:0> now = Time.now.utc
=> 2019-05-03 01:36:41 UTC
irb(main):015:0> now + (5.minutes ** 2)
=> 2019-05-04 02:36:41 UTC
```

Comment: Actually, 5 minutes squared is 25 square minutes not 25 minutes. Not sure how Ruby is choosing to interpret it.

Comment: Does `Time` have an instance method `**`?

Comment: Just doing a little light arithmetic, it looks like Ruby is using seconds. 5 minutes is 300 seconds. Squared is 90,000 seconds (actually square seconds, but Ruby is interpreting as seconds). That's 1500 minutes, or 1 day plus 1 hour. Case closed. :)

Comment: It’s squaring the seconds (25 hours = 5×5 60×60-seconds). Oof, that’s an overload that doesn’t need to exist. I’m not sure how the whole `ActiveSupport::Duration` vs. `ActiveSupport::Duration::Scalar` thing works, though and if it’s a side-effect of inheriting `Numeric` or something else.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that `(5min)^2` should equal `25min`? That is not correct math. The correct result would be `25min^2`. But what does `min^2` mean in this context?

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no `Numeric#minutes` in ruby, that’s Rails monkeypatching everything.
2. [`Numeric#minutes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-minutes) is delegated to [`ActiveSupport::Duration#minutes`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L155) which in turn constructs an [`ActiveSupport::Duratioon::Scalar`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L15) instance, with an amount of seconds as a “number behind.” That number will be used in:
3. [coercion](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L23) that might be used in any arithmetics involving `Numeric`, amongst others.

That said, when `foo.minutes` meets the arithmetic operation with a `Numeric` as a RHO, it [using coercion] does the math using the number of seconds.

Even more, the comparison against `Numeric` would also work:

```
5.minutes == 300
#⇒ true
```

Hence my advise: never ever use these misleading monkeypatched crap. Use seconds explicitly to perform date/time operations.